# How to add custom code in single.php page

Tags: html, wordpress

I want to add add a DIV (`width:342px; height:280px; float:left`) in the single.php page that should be shown in the start of the article under the title on the front hand. Here is the code of the single.php

```
<main class="content <?php echo $sidebar['content_class']; ?>"  role="main" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
            <?php // THE LOOP
            if (have_posts()) :
                do_action('radium_before_single_post_content');
                while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    $format = get_post_format();
                    if( false === $format ) { $format = 'standard'; }
                    if( is_attachment() ) { $format = 'attachment'; }
                    get_template_part( 'includes/post-formats/content', $format );
                endwhile;
                do_action('radium_after_single_post_content');
                if( $framework->theme_supports( 'comments', 'posts' ) && ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )  ) comments_template( '', true );
            endif;
            ?>
            <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="<?php the_date('c'); ?>"/>
            <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="<?php the_modified_date( 'c' ); ?>"/>
        </main>
```

Comment: I'd say, go go go! Add it! Don't be shy my friend. Or do you perhaps have a problem? If so, please tell us what the problem is exactly, and we just might can help you

Comment: Giorgio I don't exactly know that how to edit the wordpress single.php. I have mentioned the single.php code please help me to add a div tag in the post that should show under the title of the page on front panel. Please help me

Comment: In your specific case you'll have to edit `wp-content/themes/<your-theme>/includes/post-formats/content/standard.php`, it's included by the `get_template_part()` function. This is a sub-template or template part were the actual post is printed out. Note that if you have another post type (attachment post type) another template part will be used instead.

Comment: Also take into consideration that you have a paid template. Meaning: you can get free support from the developer of the theme, I think that should be the main source of help. If you have not paid for the template and just copied it from someone else: shame on you!